# Pygtk and segmentation fault

Tags: python, linux, pygtk

Why I get this segmentation fault?:

```
>>> import gtk
>>> a = gtk.Window()
>>> a.show()
>>> b = gtk.Dialog("hellooo")
>>> b.show()                 # here the dialog appears
>>> b.show()
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: i just run your code and i didn't get any Segmentation Fault !!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you install from source or using your system's packages?
I would recommend a reinstall, using `apt-get`, `yum` or similar

Comment: I haven't install anything. gtk comes with python in ubuntu 10.04 :)

Answer (score 1):

I get a segmentation fault. So don't show() a dialog after it has been shown once. The object has been created and destroyed and you are trying to reuse it. Don't do that. Make a new one. Or: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this..."

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running your code outside of a "graphical" environment. ie. one with a valid `DISPLAY` environment variable.